# Prometheus.io build_ui.sh command not found

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to build Prometheus.io from source in Windows 10 according to the [instructions](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus). Unfortunately i come across the following error via Cygwin after using `make build config.file prometheus.yml`

```
> prometheus-io@0.46.0 build
> set "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false" && bash build_ui.sh --all

build_ui.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
build_ui.sh: line 15: $'\r': command not found
: invalid optione 16: set: -
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [--] [-] [arg ...]
build_ui.sh: line 17: $'\r': command not found
build_ui.sh: line 18: syntax error in conditional expression
make: *** [ui-build] Error 127
```

after updating the [package.json](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/web/ui/package.json) **build entry** from

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false bash build_ui.sh --all",
```

to

```
"build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && bash build_ui.sh --all",
```

Any idea that could help me?

Regards